# Switch sprite animations in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, animation, sprite, cocos2d-x

I have a "GameCharacter" class where I have a sprite for my main character in the game, I loaded the frames and animations correctly. I can switch between animations with single touches or swiping gestures. Right now I can rotate between animations.

In my touch function of my scene I have this:

```
_mychar->RunAnimation(id);
```

where id is the ID of the animation, just an integer I change with every touch.

the method works like this:

```
void GameCharacter::RunAnimation(int a){

    _sprite->stopAllActions();
    if(a<_animation.size() && a>=0){
        _sprite->runAction( CCRepeatForever::create(_animation[a]));
    }
}
```

`_animation[]` is just a vector with `CCAnimate*` objects retained (I release them later when I destroy the GameCharacter).

I have 2 idle animations, I want to switch between them randomly, for example, I want to "queue" the first animation 3 to 5 times and the second 1 to 2 times, and repeat like this forever... also, I want to interrupt this "infinite random idle animation" with a touch that makes the character run another animation until it ends (for example a jump animation) and when it ends, just get to the idle animation. I don't know if I explained well, I hope you can understand me.

The id for the animations are:

- 0-idle1 (3 frames)
- 1-idle2 (6 frames)
- 2-jump (12 frames)
- 3-walk (12 frames)

Right now, i just need to be able to get the character in that idle state (random times between animation 0 and 1) and whenever touch, the jump animation is done once and at the end the idle start again...

I will solve the walking animation later.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend `schedule` method to periodically run your `idle` logic, something like this.-

```
this->schedule(schedule_selector(YourGameClass::idleLogic), FREQUENCY_IN_SECONDS);
```

In your `idleLogic` method, you may check if your character isn't running nor jumping, and if so, get a random `index` for your idle animations array, and run `_animation[index]`. It'd be also a good idea to keep track of how much time your character has been stopped, so that you don't run any idle animation unless `iddleTime >= MIN_IDLE_TIME`

Hope it helps.

Comment: perfect, and thanks for the fast response, I will check the schedule method and see how it works :)

Comment: 2 hours checking the schedule method and I don't get it at all... can you please post an example?

Comment: Mm what's exactly the problem? Did you manage to call schedule so that the selector is called periodically? I'm afraid I can't show relevant code for you as I work with objective-c Cocos2d :(